# Does additive Adjust-R square indicate variables in two models are independent?

Tags: regression, linear-model

If the adjust-R square for
model Y ~ x1 + x2 +... xn is 0.11 and
model Y ~ z1 + z2 +... zn is 0.07 and
model Y ~ x1 + x2 +... xn + z1 + z2 +... zn is 0.18, can I draw the conclusion that the object represented by x is independent from object represented by y?

Comment: Interesting question, worthy of some investigation.  But note that if you introduce one or more variables $W_i$ that are orthogonal to all the $X_j$, all the $Z_k$, *and* $Y$, then including those $W_i$ in both models will not change anything--except they will provide *prima facie* evidence of strong relationships among the independent variables in the two models!

Comment: I *really* doubt you can say anything about independence. Uncorrelated? Maybe.